# Bulk overwrite .csv files with AWK or sed

Tags: awk, sed, csv

I have a directory with many sub-directories which are all full of .csv files (no files with other extensions).

I want to overwrite all `.csv` files with a sed/AWK command in once. Moving everything to another direction is good too if the directory structure doesn't change.

The commands I use are:

1. `$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub("^([^/:]+://)?(www[.])?","",$1); sub("/.*","",$1)} 1' input_file`
2. `$ sed -E 's~(^[^/]*//)?(w+\.)?([^/]*)[^,]*~\3~' input_file`
3. `$ sed -E 's#^(.*://)?(www\.)?##; s#^([^,/]+)[^,]*#\1#' input_file`

How do I edit all files in once instead of file by file

Comment: It looks like you actually want to edit the files. But you've already got commands to do this. What part of the issue is it that you're having problems with?

Comment: I have tons of .csv files I need to edit. I don't want to edit it one by one. I want to edit everything in once

Comment: Ah. So you wanted to apply this edit to lots of files. I couldn't work out what your question was asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec awk -i inplace 'script' {} +
```

With GNU sed:

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sed -i -E 'script' +
```